# Where is the RAID configuration from WebminGUI?

Tags: server, configuration, raid, mdadm, webmin

Hi I've set up a Raid1 on two Harddrives via the Webmin GUI. Everything works fine, I get the raid shown as /dev/md127

Now, I want to make a backup and documentation off all configurations ... but **where is this config done?**

It is NOT in **/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf** where I expected it ...

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan,     using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Mon, 30 Jan 2017 08:24:24 +0100
# by mkconf $Id$
```

**So where else will I find it?**

**EDIT:** The File /etc/mdadm.conf does not exist!

**EDIT2:** Even trying to do a Backup from the Webmin-GUI only stores the /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf ...

Comment: Check here `/etc/mdadm.conf`

Comment: Or try finding it with this `dpkg -L webmin | grep /etc
`

Comment: Hi thanks, but `/etc/mdadm.conf` does not exist.
And `dpkg -L webmin | grep /etc` shows
 `/etc
/etc/pam.d
/etc/pam.d/webmin
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/webmin`

Comment: Usually, the md RAID metadata are stored on the disks themselves in the so-called 'superblock', see `man md`. They are administerd by`mdadm`. `mdadm.conf` is only used in special situations.

Comment: @ridgy thanks a lot, I guess this saves me a lot of time searching for it. So there is no config that could be backuped and for the docu I have to note what I did within the webmin-GUI?

Comment: For documentation, see the EXAMPLES section in `man mdadm`. There are examples how to create mdadm.conf from currently activen raid arrays, using option `--detail`or `--examine`.